# What does "#+(n) = " means in case of algorithms complexity?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm reading a book called "From Mathematics to Generic Programming" by Alexander A. Stepanov and Daniel E. Rose, the second chapter contains a description of Egyptian Multiplication algorithm. Its complexity described as `#+(n) = [log n] + (ν(n) - 1)`. In general it's totally understandable but what does "#+" means? Is it a form of notation for a mathematic function or something?

Answer (score 4):

'#' often denotes "the number of", and the '+' sign is used as an index. So we have "the number of additions".

Answer (score 1):

In that book before giving the equation, the author says,

> How many additions is multiply1 going to do?
> Every time we call the function, we’ll need to do the addition indicated by the + in a + a.
> Since we are halving the value as we recurse, we’ll invoke the
> function *log* n times. And some of the time, we’ll need to do
> another addition indicated by the + in result + a.
> ***So the total number of additions will be
> `#+(n) = ⌊log n⌋ + (ν(n) − 1)`***

```
int multiply1(int n, int a) {
    if (n == 1) return a;
    int result = multiply1(half(n), a + a);
    if (odd(n)) result = result + a;
    return result;
}
bool odd(int n) { return n & 0x1; }
int half(int n) { return n >> 1; }
```